# How to re-calculate the shipping estimation on changing payment method in checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, order-summary

Our store has a shipping method which takes the sum of order's items values to estimate the shipping methods values.

The problem is, when I've a cart rule by payment method, the discount is applied only when the customer selects that method, but the shipping estimation isn't called in this process, resulting in different value on Order Summary.

So, How can I force the shipping estimation on select a different payment method ?

Thanks in advance.